# Artificially-created diamond 'windows' for spacecraft

Tags: technology, chemistry, space-constructs

In the past I've entertained the notion of space stations and spaceships having window panes or transparent viewing surfaces made from laboratory-created diamonds, but a recent answer to a different question on this site has led me to question how effective (or *not*) this would be even if it were possible- assuming it is even possible to create diamonds with the appropriate dimensions for a viewport on such a structure- would they serve as safe and effective for the task?

Comment: More likely you'd be working with something like synthetic _sapphire_, as sapphire is less brittle, has greater optical purity, and has a _much_ higher heat tolerance than diamond.  (For reference, diamond can ignite at 850C.)

Comment: I don't get it. What is the *real* problem that diamond windows are supposed to solve? What can diamond do which (relatively) ordinary glasses such as fused silica cannot?

Comment: @jdunlop is right sapphire is better, artificial sapphire is even used for some real world applications where optics have to survive in really harsh environments.

Comment: See _[Sapphire (wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphire) > Synthetic Sapphire > Applications_

Comment: In "The Mote in God's eye" They don'y SAY that it's diamond, but it almost certainly is: " ... And earlier he’d been looking at the crystal. “Yes, Mr. Whitbread,” Rod
said. “It’s very strong.” ... “Tablecloth, silverware,
plates, platters, crystal, all have to be fairly durable,” ... “Mere glassware wouldn’t
last the first battle. Our crystal is something else. It was cut from the windscreen of a wrecked First Empire reentry vehicle. Or so I was told. It’s certain we can’t make such materials any longer. ... " --> Page 20 of 334 ...

Comment: ... [here](https://ia902802.us.archive.org/22/items/LarryNivenAndJerryPournelleTheMoteInGodsEye/Larry%20Niven%20and%20Jerry%20Pournelle%20-%20The%20Mote%20in%20Gods%20Eye.pdf)

Comment: and - In "Red Mars" (or Green?) they build space elevators from diamomd. - none of which makes it possible :-)

Comment: I don't have any references to point to but I read somewhere that if one were to make glass on the moon or some other place lacking in atmosphere it would be incredibly hard due to no moisture causing impurities during crystalline structure formation. I can't find anything besides (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10853-018-3101-y) and articles about glass/ water beads recently identified by China's moon rover.

Comment: username checks out

Comment: diamonds are flammable. Not great for spacecraft material.

Comment: [Is Sapphire Stone Used as Windshields on Military Aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88294/is-sapphire-stone-used-as-windshields-on-military-aircraft)

Comment: @RIanGillis while water might be a factor affecting strength, one of the defining characteristics of glasses is that they're non-crystalline.

Answer (score 19):

Diamond is very hard, but unfortunately [it is also a bit brittle](https://youtu.be/eNYiKRJwUBU?t=29). If an object with enough kinetic energy hits it, the window can shatter completely. This is not an acceptable risk in space. Suitable window material should not shatter even if it breaks.

Eg. [car windshields had this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windshield#Safety), and that is why they are today made of [laminated glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminated_glass) to mitigate this risk. If the glass is hit, the glass cracks, but typically [the windshield still stays as one piece](https://cdn.abcotvs.com/dip/images/12899694_030123-wls-windshield-ice-6a-vosot-vid.jpg?w=1600). Maybe it is possible to do something similar with your spacecraft windows, ie. use diamond instead of glass and laminate it to prevent shattering.

Comment: Just to nitpick (for those not following the link): Windshields are intentionally designed to shatter, and in a specific way (many small pieces, no sharp edges). I do support the idea of laminated diamond/glass.

Comment: @Tom: Modern windshields are indeed designed so that *if* they shatter they do so in a specific less-harmful way — but also to be highly shatter-resistant, compared to older forms of glass.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine agreed. Though we should tell that to the million or so idiots on YouTube who thought you could dance on a windshield or whatever and look all surprised when - omg! - glass does indeed shatter...

Comment: This might be a bit about semantics, but they seem to make an intentional distinction between _shattering_ and _cracking_ in this context. Laminated glass is often called shatterfree or shatterproof. It can still crack, but usually it stays as one piece, held together with the the plastic or something similar.

Comment: Car windshields and spaceship windows are very different use cases. The primary concern with car windshields was to avoid sharp glass fragments from high-force impacts. For spaceships, on the other hand, the goal is presumably to prevent any hole whatsoever from generally-tiny meteors and potentially from accidents.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I think they are essentially the same problem: no holes and no fragments. Also car windshields have to withstand high-velocity impacts from rocks, and the windshield has to stop them (no holes); and if impact on a spacecraft window creates _any_ loose fragments, then the structural integrity of window is severely compromised (no fragments).

Comment: @JaniMiettinen "Stop a rock from entering by any means necessary, and also don't generate sharp shards" is very different from "prevent even the smallest hole by any means necessary". They may overlap in what they achieve, but for a car window, you *generally* don't care about small holes and medium-term structural integrity. You just care about minimising passenger damage from the initial impact.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I still see only only quantitative difference: spacecraft window has to endure _more_ due to incredibly harsh conditions in space, and lack of service stations every 10 miles. Could you provide an aspect that is clearly _unique_ to spacecraft, not just something that has to be more durable or more something else. I only can think of one: protection from radiation. That is not needed in car windshield.

Comment: @JaniMiettinen I did provide "an aspect that is clearly unique to spacecraft", twice: preventing holes (but okay, not "by any means necessary", as small holes aren't anywhere near catastrophic). Cars couldn't care less about holes after impact, because outside the window is where the stuff you breathe is, and you'll need to replace your windshield after any non-trivial impact anyway (and often after trivial impacts too - cars aren't made to be durable, they're made to protect you from roughly 1 accident).

Comment: @NotThatGuy Car windshield _has_ to protect against holes, too, because if a rock hits the windshield, and it manages to make a hole, the rock will go through and potentially kill the driver or a passenger. You are on the right tract about that it cannot provide 100 % protection, but neither can any spacecraft window, because undamageable materials do not exist. The only difference is how much it must and can withstand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148546/discussion-between-jani-miettinen-and-notthatguy).

Answer (score 14):

Diamond is good for some things like cutting, but not for things like resisting impacts. It is very hard, and consequently very brittle. Laminating might counteract that weakness, but I doubt it would make much sense in terms of weight and budget.

We're already in the future anyways.

[Transparent ceramics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_ceramics#Armor) are a thing already, and it will only get better and cheaper. ISS' Cupola module uses "[fused silica and borosilicate glass panes](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/stationpayloads/cupola.html)" for its 7 windows, and shutters to protect them when not in use. It's been working fine for the last 13 years, they even managed to replace panes.

We've also created things like aluminium oxynitride which can make for much light bulletproof panes, or sapphire which is already used in iPhone lenses.

The military is very interested in those things, because lightweight and transparent materials have a lot of interesting applications, so it's safe to bet we'll be able to make transparent viewports that aren't total structural weaknesses by the time we're able to make cool spaceships.

But it won't be diamond. Diamond just isn't the right material for armor.

If you really want diamond, I can see two options.

You could imagine a carbon-based material, like a transparent carbon ceramic nanotube matrix thingamajig, and call it "diamond window" because diamonds are carbon and marketing will probably still exist in the future.

Or you could have a diamond pane under a proper transparent ceramic pane, and that's technically a diamond window (with non-diamond transparent armor).

Comment: "But it won't be diamond. Diamond just isn't the right material for armor." Minecraft lied to me

Comment: I thought shuttles would have different material since they have to go back and forth between Earth and orbit, but turns out they also use [fused silica](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19950019959/downloads/19950019959.pdf) with perfect record.

Comment: +1 for referencing aluminium oxynitride. Worth adding the Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride

Comment: @MBender Ah, good old "transparent aluminium." Scotty would be proud 

Answer (score 9):

Diamonds isn't particularly resistant to impact, with a fracture toughness of 2 MPam<sup>1/2</sup>. If you want a resistant and transparent material, you could instead use Yttria-stabilized cubic zirconia (bonus for the cool name), with about 3.7 MPam<sup>1/2</sup>, or sapphire with 4.2 MPam<sup>1/2</sup>.

If the goal is to have highly impact resistant material, going for a composite structure is probably much better. Stacking layers of transparent materials in a similar way an armor is built could make for a very strong material. Laminated sapphire with graphene could be extremely resistant. Adding a shock absorbing material like polycarbonate can greatly improve impact resistance while staying transparent.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for the image?

Comment: @WaterMolecule Made it myself

Comment: LOL @typo "choc absorbing material".  Sometimes, *I'm* made from that.

Comment: @Kingsley My brain switched to French mid-sentence lol

Answer (score 6):

"Windows are structural weaknesses. Geth do not use them." - Legion, Mass effect 2

Why would you need windows anyway? If you want to look outside you can have a sensor outside and a screen inside. Same results with none of the engineering issues. And if you are afraid that an insane A.I., khm, your friendly computer will try to manipulate the view you can make it a closed system and not connect it to the network.

Because windows made of any material WILL be a weakness in the structure. And if you somehow create a transparent material better than what the hull is made of, then why not create the whole thing from that transparent material?

Comment: Also a window sized monitor will be much, much cheaper than a window sized diamond. Better view, no chance to burn your retina if there is a high energy flare. We are even replacing mirrors in cars with monitors to ensure perfect alignment as well as better view clarity under different conditions.

Comment: I'd say humans aren't robots, humans like to look out of windows and a screen just doesn't hit the same.

Comment: @AmiralPatate We can build screens today that a human eye cannot distinguish from a window.

Comment: @Negdo But you know it's not a window.

Comment: If the entire hull was transparent, you'd need fluffy curtains for the bashful.  Oh, and everyone can see how much food, water, ammunition, ... you're carrying.  Even in the vast emptiness of space you need *some* privacy!

Comment: @AmiralPatate A few hundred years ago: "Humans are used to look through wall openings! Looking through that new material, glass, just doesn't feel the same. And how expensive that glass is! A window should be a wind opening, that's where the name comes from. You shouldn't call a glass pane a window. This stupid new fanciness will be gone in less than 5 years, I swear!"

Comment: @CemKalyoncu, monitors in cars are far from perfect. There is a non-negligible lag, and you cannot focus your sight on an object behind you when the "mirror" is a flat screen. Those disadvantages may be irrelevant in a spacecraft, though.

Comment: @Kingsley all you need is a thin sheet of something inside the spacecraft for privacy.

Answer (score 4):

Synthetic diamond can be used as an armor material. It's no different from AlON, sapphire, or just plain glass in that regard. All armor ceramics are brittle, by their very nature. Diamond isn't particularly more brittle than the rest.

However, it's notoriously difficult to fabricate, the only means to make flat diamonds is through chemical or physical vapor deposition, which is hard to do in a thick layer. You also still need to layer it with tougher polymer layers. There's no massive advantage to using diamond over sapphire or AlON. But diamond-like coatings are used widely where a very hard surface is required. [This includes optics](https://www.edmundoptics.eu/knowledge-center/application-notes/optics/diamond-like-carbon-coatings/).

The primary advantage of ceramics in armor is their hardness, allowing them to blunt incoming metal projectiles. In space, you are more likely to face hypervelocity projectiles, against which hardness doesn't help much. Brittleness, however, isn't such a big problem either.

A window with its outermost layer made out of diamond will likely retain its transparency longer, better resisting the effects of space dust than other ceramics. In all other respects, it won't be very different from AlON or glass. If you're in a high sci-fi setting, and don't want to use the same aluminum oxynitride as everyone else probably does, there's nothing very wrong with diamond.